# Signed assembly generates an "Application has stopped working" on SOAP deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, soap, crash, assemblies

I'm instantiating an object, and filling it up using SOAP data.

This used to work well.

However, after giving the assembly a strong name, I'm getting the following error:

[image: error window]

The important bits being:

> Application has stopped working
>
> Problem Signature: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap

The debugger shows me a `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException`, with the following details. Notice how the serialization parser complains of 'no assembly associated with Xml key'

[image: debugger]

The full error description is:

> Parse Error, no assembly associated with Xml key a1:http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MyProject/MyProject%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull MainForm

Here's the StackTrace

> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.ProcessGetType(String value, String xmlKey, String& assemblyString)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.ProcessType(ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.ProcessAttributes(ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.StartChildren()
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapParser.ParseXml()
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapParser.Run()
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, ISerParser serParser)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream)
>
> at MyProject.Program.Main() in C:\MyProject\Program.cs:line 35
>
> at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>
> at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

I unchecked "Sign the assembly", rebuilt the solution, and, like magic, everything went back to normal--so, I know a bad SOAP file is not the root cause. In fact, if I had to venture a guess, I'd say the strong assembly name is 'confusing' the SOAP deserializer.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What the error from screenshot saying? Starting with "Parse error..."

Comment: @sll Gives the full path to the entry point that calls the deserialization method. I've edited the post to include this info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message

> Parse Error, no assembly associated with Xml key
>   a1:http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MyProject/MyProject%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull

indicates that the data has been serialized with an assembly that has a PublicKeyToken set to null. This means that at serialization time, this assembly had no strong name.

Now, if you recompile this assembly sign it using a strong name, and redeploy it inplace without chaning the serialized data, the assembly identity will not be considered the same, and the deserialization code will not be able to use it for deserialization, hence the error.

Assemblies used for serialization and deserialization must have the same full name (at least with the formatter and the binder you use).

So it can be a deployment issue (make sure serializing & deserializing assemblies have the same full name), or if you really need to be able to deal with assemblies with different full name (but that's unusual), you can use a custom binder, like what's done here: [Deserializing data into a dynamically loaded Assembly](http://techdigger.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/deserializing-data-into-a-dynamically-loaded-assembly/) although I would not recommend it for standard operations.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I had reached this conclusion a few days ago, but I wanted to see a bit more on the issue. Your answer gave me that extra info and confidence in my solution.